# Is there partial gravitational shielding?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, gravity, energy-conservation, gravitational-waves

Gravitational waves carry energy. The sticky bead argument shows that this energy can be extracted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bead_argument

But Lee Smolin points out that

> "In principle, nothing can screen out the force of gravity or stop the propagation of gravitational waves, so nothing can be perfectly isolated. I discovered this important point during my PhD studies. I wanted to model a box that contained gravitational waves bouncing back and forth inside, but my models kept failing, because the gravitational waves passed right through the walls".

Gravitational shielding is considered to be a violation of the equivalence principle and therefore inconsistent with both Newtonian theory and general relativity, and there is no experimental evidence for it.

If energy from gravitational waves can be extracted, does this mean that partial gravitational shielding exists?

Comment: More on [sticky bead](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22sticky%20bead%22).

Answer (score 3):

There are two separate issues here.

First is the question of whether a gravitational wave can be absorbed. The answer is yes; for example, the absorption cross section of gravitational waves impinging on black holes has been computed in references like [1], and on resonant mass detectors in [2]. The absorption of gravitational waves is *not* what is meant by gravitational shielding.

Second is the question of whether a *static* gravitational field can be *screened*. In electromagnetism, screening can occur in a conductor because charges can arrange themselves on the surface of the conductor to create an opposing field that cancels the applied field inside the conductor. This effect does not happen in gravity because gravity is universally attractive. This is what people mean when they say gravitational shielding would violate the equivalence principle.

References

[1] https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269317307608

[2] https://academic.oup.com/book/41655/chapter-abstract/353717554?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: A gravitational wave can be absorbed, that is a statement in my question. If gravitational waves (or equivalently, gravitons), and be absorbed, why can't a static gravitational field be screened? Isn't the gravitational field communicating through spacetime just by gravitational waves that can be screened?

Comment: @Manuel No, the static field is not communicated by gravitational waves. If you like it's communicated by off shell gravitons, as opposed to on shell gravitons (which correspond to gravitational waves). On shell gravitons can appear in external states and can be absorbed. Off shell gravitons mediate a gravitational force between masses and this force can't be canceled by a clever arrangement of masses, unlike in electromagnetism.

Comment: could you explain further how and why are static gravitational fields created by off shell gravitons?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there partial gravitational shielding?

For a suitable definition of “shielding”, yes!

There is an interesting result of Carlotto & Schoen [1], who established that *gravitational fields can be shielded away by gravitational fields*, at least instantaneously!

The original paper is rather technical, so I would recommend a more accessible exposition [2] by Chrusciel, who gives the following statement of the main result of [1]:

> Given an asymptotically flat initial data set for vacuum Einstein equations there exist cones and asymptotically flat vacuum initial data which coincide with the original ones inside the cones and are Minkowskian outside slightly larger cones.

Note, here we are dealing with *Einstein constraint equations*, equations for the asymptotically flat initial (Cauchy) data for Einstein equations specified on a spacelike hypersurface representing a *single moment* in time. This shield, in essence is comprised of a system of gravitational waves which carry finite total energy (while being infinite in spatial extent). And if we evolve that initial data forward in time then the “shield” would be dissipating as the waves comprising it disperse (of course for the waves propagating with finite speed $c$ it would take infinite time to disperse completely, but any point at a finite distance from the shielded region would eventually “feel” the gravitational fields from which it was shielded initially.

The nonlinear character of the gravitational field is not essential for this construction and, in fact, there is a simplified version of this result for the linearized gravity in [3]. That paper also shows that it is possible to *shield (instantaneously) electromagnetic field using electromagnetic field* and also greatly increases the possible choices in geometries of shielded regions.

As we can see, what mathematical physicists call “shielding” may not coincide with the image that words “gravitational shield” evoke in a reader of science fiction.

1. Carlotto, A., & Schoen, R. (2016). *Localizing solutions of the Einstein constraint equations*. Inventiones mathematicae, 205, 559-615, [doi:10.1007/s00222-015-0642-4](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-015-0642-4), [arXiv:1407.4766](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4766).
2. Chruściel, P. T. (2016). *Anti-gravity à la Carlotto–Schoen*. [arXiv:1611.01808](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01808).
3. Beig, R., & Chruściel, P. T. (2017). *Shielding linearized gravity*. Physical Review D, 95(6), 064063, [doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.95.064063](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.95.064063), [arXiv:1701.00486](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.00486).