Is it possible to change the amount of gravity applied to an object?
The question might be silly. I'm not a physics student either my question might be asked incorrectly. I would love to learn from you.
Is it possible to change the gravitational force applied to an object? or alter that force to some extent in an area?
Or is the gravity something 'solid' that nothing affects or nothing changes it?
Thanks in advance.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/774397/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342658/2451 and links therein.
